# How to trigger jenkins maven job with multiple branches when a SNAPSHOT dependency is built?

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, git-flow

I have a maven project: **myApplication** stored on a git repository. It depends on another project **myLibrary** stored on another git repository.
myApplication and myLibrary have a **develop** and **release-candidate** versions pushed on distinct branches.

I configured a jenkins job to poll the develop and release-candidate branches of myApplication. Another jenkins job polls develop and release-candidate branches of myLibrary.
I also configured the Jenkins job for myApplication to "Build whenever a snapshot dependency is build".

The problem is that when a SNAPSHOT of the develop version of myLibrary is build, it doesn't always trigger a build of myApplication on the develop branch but on **the last branch**, which can be develop or release-candidate.

Is there a way to configure jenkins to trigger only the build on the develop branch of myApplication when the develop SNAPSHOT of myLibrary is built? If not, is there a possibility to trigger the build on all of the branches of myApplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We Finally managed the issue using the [jenkins multi-branch plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multi-Branch+Project+Plugin).

Comment: how..........?!